# Do I need a visa for a connecting flight at CDG from T1 to T2E?

Tags: schengen-visas, layovers, connecting-flights, chinese-citizens, cdg

I hold a Chinese passport with a UK tourist visa. I will be landing at T1 (flight CZ347 from China to CDG) and need to catch a connecting flight at T2E to the UK (flight AF1058 from CDG to Newcastle). Both flights are on a single ticket and my checked luggage will go all the way to the UK so I don't need to pick it up in CDG. In this case, will I be required to get a Schengen visa? And is a 3-hour layover long enough to catch the connecting flight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Answer (score 1):

> In this case, will I be required to get a Schengen Visa?

No, you won't need a Schengen visa since you won't be leaving the international transit area on your way to the UK. As @jcaron helpfully points out, it is not universal and some nationalities do need an airport transit visa even for a through transit like that, Chinese citizens are exempt from that.

To get to 2E, you will need to take the blue shuttle (the shuttle is in the international zone)

[image]

> And is a 3-hour layover long enough to catch the connecting flight?

It is long enough, and if the previous flight is delayed, you would be accomodated as it is a single ticket

Comment: Note for future readers: this is not universal, citizens of some countries need an airport transit visa (ATV) even if they stay airside.  Not the case at this time for Chinese citizens though.